# Ajax add to cart with quantity is working only once for my woocommerce website

Tags: woocommerce

On the shop page for my [website](http://thejobupdates.com/pt/masonbaker/shop/), I have implemented add to cart with ajax functionality along with a quantity input.

I have used code snippet from a referred [website](http://www.themeplumber.com/woocommerce-add-quantity-to-shop-page/).

The functionality is working with ajax. So, if I enter 10 in the quantity box and click on 'Add to cart' then 10 products are added to the cart through ajax. But the problem is if in the same quantity box (for the same product) if I want to add 5 more and if I enter 5 in the box and hit 'Add to cart' it adds 10 items again and not 5.

So, it just holds the 10 value and keeps adding that no matter what I put in the quantity box. You can check it on my [website](http://thejobupdates.com/pt/masonbaker/shop/).

So, if anyone can help me to solve this problem by having a look at my code below.

The code snippets are as follows:

Replaced the add-to-cart.php file with the following code:

**add-to-cart.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Custom Loop Add to Cart.
 *
 * Template with quantity and ajax.
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly.

global $product;
?>

<?php if ( ! $product->is_in_stock() ) : ?>

    <a href="<?php echo apply_filters( 'out_of_stock_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) ); ?>" class="button"><?php echo apply_filters( 'out_of_stock_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) ); ?></a>

<?php else : ?>

    <?php
        $link = array(
            'url'   => '',
            'label' => '',
            'class' => ''
        );

        switch ( $product->product_type ) {
            case "variable" :
                $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'variable_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'variable_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Select options', 'woocommerce' ) );
            break;
            case "grouped" :
                $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'grouped_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'grouped_add_to_cart_text', __( 'View options', 'woocommerce' ) );
            break;
            case "external" :
                $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'external_add_to_cart_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'external_add_to_cart_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) );
            break;
            default :
                if ( $product->is_purchasable() ) {
                    $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_url', esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ) );
                    $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_text', __( 'Add to cart', 'woocommerce' ) );
                    $link['class']  = apply_filters( 'add_to_cart_class', 'add_to_cart_button' );
                } else {
                    $link['url']    = apply_filters( 'not_purchasable_url', get_permalink( $product->id ) );
                    $link['label']  = apply_filters( 'not_purchasable_text', __( 'Read More', 'woocommerce' ) );
                }
            break;
        }

        // If there is a simple product.
        if ( $product->product_type == 'simple' ) {
            ?>
            <form action="<?php echo esc_url( $product->add_to_cart_url() ); ?>" class="cart" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <?php
                    // Displays the quantity box.
                    woocommerce_quantity_input();

                    // Display the submit button.
                    echo sprintf( '<button type="submit" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" data-quantity="1" class="%s button product_type_simple">%s</button>', esc_attr( $product->id ), esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ), esc_attr( $link['class'] ), esc_html( $link['label'] ) );
                ?>
            </form>
            <?php
        } else {
          echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', sprintf('<a href="%s" rel="nofollow" data-product_id="%s" data-product_sku="%s" class="%s button product_type_%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $link['url'] ), esc_attr( $product->id ), esc_attr( $product->get_sku() ), esc_attr( $link['class'] ), esc_attr( $product->product_type ), esc_html( $link['label'] ) ), $product, $link );
        }

    ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Added the following code to functions.php file:

**functions.php**

```
function cs_wc_loop_add_to_cart_scripts() {
    if ( is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() || is_product() || is_front_page() || is_home() ) : ?>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
        $(document).on( 'change', '.quantity .qty', function() {
            $(this).parent('.quantity').next('.add_to_cart_button').attr('data-quantity', $(this).val());
        });
    });
</script>

    <?php endif;
}

add_action( 'wp_footer', 'cs_wc_loop_add_to_cart_scripts' );
```

**quantity-input.php**

```
<div class="quantity"><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="minus">-</a><input type="number" step="<?php echo esc_attr( $step ); ?>" <?php if ( is_numeric( $min_value ) ) : ?>min="<?php echo esc_attr( $min_value ); ?>"<?php endif; ?> <?php if ( is_numeric( $max_value ) ) : ?>max="<?php echo esc_attr( $max_value ); ?>"<?php endif; ?> name="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_name ); ?>" value="<?php echo esc_attr( $input_value ); ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr_x( 'Qty', 'Product quantity input tooltip', 'woocommerce' ) ?>" class="input-text qty text" size="4" /><a href="javascript:void(0)" class="plus">+</a></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think data-quantity will not work correctly with `.attr()`.

Use `.data()`.. Replace this code..

```
$(this).parent('.quantity').next('.add_to_cart_button').attr('data-quantity', $(this).val());
```

Try something like this..

```
$(this).closest('form').find('.add_to_cart_button').data('quantity', this.value);
```

Comment: But there is a slight problem though, if I type the value into the quantity box then it gets added properly, but if I use the plus or minus buttons to add or reduce the number of items, then it is not working. I guess the onchange is not detecting the new value.

Comment: So, please help me if you can figure out, why it is not working with the buttons.

Comment: you should check how `+` and `-` works.. and call `.change()` in there.... currently in your question, I can't see the code for it...

Comment: Can you please have a look at the live website, because I think the value is changing but it is not being read by the on change function.

http://thejobupdates.com/pt/masonbaker/shop/

Thanks for your time

Comment: woocommerce_quantity_input(); this code outputs both quantity box and the plus and minus symbol. So, I think the jquery code snippet edit you suggested should work for both. but it isn't

Comment: `woocommerce_quantity_input()` uses `input type="number"` by default of woocommerce without the `+` and `-`... somewhere in your theme or plugin is changing it...

Comment: try to look for this file, `yourtheme/woocommerce/global/quantity-input.php`

Comment: Ok. found the file. and thanks for the info. It is being added. But I do want to keep the plus, minus buttons with quantity. what do you suggest? do you want me to remove them? or can I change something in the javascript

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102774/discussion-between-reigel-and-kiran-kumar-dash).

Comment: $(".plus").click(function() {
        var text = $(this).prev("input");
  var va = parseInt(text.val(), 10) + 1;
        text.attr('value',parseInt(text.val(), 10) + 1);
  text.parent().next('.add_to_cart_button').attr('data-quantity',va);
    });
    $(".minus").click(function() {
        var text = $(this).next("input");
  
        if(text.val() > 0){
    var va = parseInt(text.val(), 10) - 1;
          text.attr('value',parseInt(text.val(), 10) - 1);
    text.parent().next('.add_to_cart_button').attr('data-quantity',va);
        }
  
    });

Comment: Hi, I did find out the js code used for the plus and minus button. I modified it a little bit to change the data-attribute, but nothing helped. can you please give a look.